# Excel | Match combination of two columns against multiple pattern options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to check whether a combination of two columns within a table fits a specific pattern or not.

All valid combinations are recorded in a respective reference table.

Column1 needs to fit the exact value in the reference table while Column2 only needs to contain the string in the reference table

*Table to check*

| Column1 | Column2 | Pattern_fullfilled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Lorem ipsum | TRUE |
| A | dolor sit | FALSE |
| B | Lorem ipsum | FALSE |
| B | dolor sit | TRUE |
| ... | ... | ... |

*Reference table*

| Column1_Pattern (column A) | Column2_Pattern (column B) |
| --- | --- |
| A | ipsum |
| A | amet |
| B | dolor |

So far, I'm using the following formula which needs a manual `OR` component for every row of the reference table (which is located in tab "REF_Tab"):

```
OR(
AND([@[Column1]]='REF_Tab'!$A$2;ISNUMBER(SEARCH('REF_Tab'!$B$2;[@[Column2]])));
AND([@[Column1]]='REF_Tab'!$A$3;ISNUMBER(SEARCH('REF_Tab'!$B$3;[@[Column2]])));
AND([@[Column1]]='REF_Tab'!$A$4;ISNUMBER(SEARCH('REF_Tab'!$B$4;[@[Column2]])));
)
```

Is there a way to make this formula more effective, e.g., by querying the reference table's columns instead of individual fields for each row, or by using matrix formulas?

The challenge is that the formula needs to check multiple patterns for the same value in Column1 (as you can see in the exemplary reference table), hence a simple `VLOOKUP` or `VLOOKUP` won't work.

Comment: Which one is your desired result, `Pattern_fullfilled`?

Comment: Yes, column `Pattern_fullfilled` depicts the desired result based on the patterns in the reference table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `XLOOKUP()` using wildcards to assert the substring is has leading/trailing spaces:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=OR(XLOOKUP(" *"&F$2:F$4&" *"," "&B2&" ",A2,0,2)=E$2:E$4)
```

---

Or spill this dynamically in a single go using `BYROW()` to take both columns into consideration:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=BYROW(A2:B5,LAMBDA(x,OR(XLOOKUP(" *"&F2:F4&" *"," "&DROP(x,,1)&" ",TAKE(x,,1),0,2)=E2:E4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try-

```
=OR(COUNTIFS(B2,"*"&FILTER($F$2:$F$4,$E$2:$E$4=A2)&"*"))
```

For dynamic spill output, try-

```
=MAP(A2:A5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,y,OR(COUNTIFS(y,"*"&FILTER($F$2:$F$4,$E$2:$E$4=x)&"*"))))
```

To avoid false positives, use ***search*** method.

```
=MAP(A2:A5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,y,OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FILTER($G$2:$G$4,$F$2:$F$4=x),y)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea with `OR()`. Be carefull about false positives though using `COUNTIFS()`.

Comment: Yes, I should go with text comparison than countifs.

Comment: I have update my answer using search function.

Comment: Better, but be aware it still finds false positives untill you account for trailing/leading spaces. Add any letter behind "lorem ipsum" in B2, and you'll see what I mean.